# How do you calculate the likelihood of a population having or not a characteristic given a population of X where you have knowledge of a subset of X

Tags: mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, proportion

As an example, I want to know how many people in a town of 1000 people have blue eyes given that I have seen 50 of them (randomly) and of those 50 there is 2 who have blue eyes.
Given my known 50, 4% of them have blue eyes. I have knowledge of 5% of the population. How would I characterise the confidence of my 4% being accurate given both the size of my knowledge (50 people) and the total population (1000 people)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval

Comment: Hi and welcome to CV. This seems like a text book question, is it assigned or home work or self-study?

Comment: hi cherub, it's actually a work problem. The above is not the actual problem, it's an example so that I can try and understand the underlying principles. I know this is probably a fairly easy problem for someone with a stats background, however lacking that I'm finding it difficult to know where to look to find the answer. Hope that clarifies and I appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Because you work on the finite population, so please check "survey sampling". When calculating the CI, need to adjust the sampling fraction.

Comment: thanks for the link logistic. after reading about binomial proportion CI this doesn't seem to fully fit the picture as the assumption "the probability of success is the same for each trial" doesn't hold true here. I.e. although I don't know the number of blue eyes in the pop of 1000, it is a set number and my confidence in 4% would be extremely high if the total population was 51 and much lower given the pop of 1000. The survey sampling seems to be relevant, however I'm not sure how this fits in.

Comment: The population size correction is negligible when the population is large. The binomial approach effectively treats this as an infinite population, or a sampling with replacement situation, and would give you a good approximation to the finite population scenario if the population size is 1000. I don't know what you mean re: the probability of success is the same with each trial. If you have a random sample I don't see why each randomly selected person doesn't have the same probability of having blue eyes. If they do, then what characterizes that randomness ?

Comment: @logistic 50/1000 is negligible?